# Duplicate column name 'user_id' problem

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I'm having a problem trying to count the number of user records according to the user's id, however I'm using a subquery to join 2 tables that one has a count parameter but I get an error saying `duplicate column name 'user_id`.

The query:

```
$sql = "SELECT loc.location_id,
               COUNT(loc.location_id) AS total_records
        FROM locations loc
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT usr.*,
                  loc.*
            FROM 
            (
                members usr

                INNER JOIN locations loc
            ) 
            WHERE usr.user_id = " . $user_id . "
            AND usr.account_disabled = 0
            ORDER BY loc.submit_date DESC
        ) usr ON (loc.user_id = usr.user_id)";
```

All I need it is to return the user's info and the `total_records` count done by the `COUNT` function.

Cheers.

**EDIT:**

This is what I get returned for this SQL:

```
 SELECT loc.location_id,
       loc.street_name,
       loc.city,
       loc.state,
       loc.county,
       loc.country,
       usr.user_id,
       usr.username,
       COUNT(loc.location_id) AS total_records
 FROM  locations loc
 INNER JOIN members usr ON (loc.user_id = usr.user_id)              
 WHERE loc.user_id = $user_id
 AND   usr.account_disabled = 0
 GROUP BY loc.location_id
```

[image]

Comment: It is not a "query" it is mix of php and query. Strip out all variables (replace them with actual values) and put raw sql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear why you've got the derived resultset or the `LEFT JOIN`. Try this:

```
 SELECT    loc.location_id,
           COUNT(loc.location_id) AS total_records
 FROM        LOCATIONS_TABLE   loc
 INNER JOIN  MEMBERS_TABLE   usr
      ON (loc.user_id = usr.user_id)              
 WHERE loc.user_id =   $user_id  
 AND   usr.account_disabled = 0
 GROUP BY loc.location_id
```

Comment: Hmmm. Works well, but only returns one record (must be because of the limitation of the user_id that there is only 1 user) but I have multiple records done by the user and I need to return those records done by the user (including the count of number of records).

Comment: Hey. Can you help out, please? :-)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I'm afraid. If I remove the `COUNT(loc.location_id) AS total_records` it will show the user's records. But leaving it there will return 1 user record.

Comment: @lolwut: you bet; I've edited the answer to use `INNER JOIN`; How does that work?

Comment: @lolwut: can you post some sample data and show the expected results if you didn't expect 1?

Comment: I've added a screenshot for the data I get returned.

Comment: *bump* seems quiet in here, shall I post a new question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this part:

```
SELECT usr.*,
       loc.*
```

Both tables have a user_id